# Как исправить зависание страницы сайта?

Tags: google-chrome, браузер

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, зависает страница если большое количество времени не активна вкладка браузера, когда переходишь на вкладку отвисает примерно через 3-5 секунд.

Когда находишся на странице все работает быстро и исправно.

Для примера есть простое отображение даты и времени на сайте, обновляется каждую секунду, примерно похожих скриптов на сайте несколько, таймеры, анимации и всякое прочее

Я так понимаю вкладка браузера наверное кешируется, если ли возможность ее не кешировать?

ПК относильно не слабый, причина явно не в нем, какие есть варианты убрать это зависание?

```js
function dateTime(mask = 'd.m.y h:i:s', time = false, split = false) {
    let now = time ? new Date(parseInt(time)) : new Date();
    let data = {
        d: split ? now.getDate().toString() : ('0'+ now.getDate()).slice(-2),
        m: ('0'+ (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        y: now.getFullYear(),
        h: split ? now.getHours().toString() : ('0'+ now.getHours()).slice(-2),
        i: ('0'+ now.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
        s: ('0'+ now.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
    };
    return [...mask].reduce((res, el) => {
        return res += data[el] || el;
    }, '');
}

setInterval(function() {
  document.querySelector('.timer').innerHTML = dateTime();
}, 1000)
```

```html
<div class="timer"></div>
```

Comment: Ваш setInterval не работает каждую секунду, а молотит без остановки

Comment: @SwaD поправил, добавил 1000, это был просто пример